# problema con estructuras en c

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

buenas noches, tengo este codigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

struct promedios{
    char nombre[40];
    float promedio;
}p[MAX];


void cargarDatos(struct promedios pr[MAX]){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printf("Nombre : ");
        fgets(pr[i].nombre, sizeof(pr[i].nombre), stdin);
        strtok(pr[i].nombre, "\n");

        printf("Promedio : ");
        scanf("%f", &pr[i].promedio);

        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){ }

    }
}

void devuelvoDatos(struct promedios pr[MAX]){

    float mayor = pr[0].promedio;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX - i - 1; j++){
            if(pr[j].promedio > pr[j+1].promedio){
                float aux;
                aux = pr[j].promedio;
                pr[j].promedio = pr[j+1].promedio;
                pr[j+1].promedio = aux;

                char auxx;
                strcpy(auxx,pr[j].nombre);
                strcpy(pr[j].nombre,pr[j+1].nombre);
                strcpy(pr[j+1].nombre,auxx);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int f = 0; f < MAX; f++){
        printf("Nombre : %s, promedio : %.2f\n",pr[f].nombre,pr[f].promedio);
    }

}

int main(){



    cargarDatos(p);

    devuelvoDatos(p);

    return 0;
}
```

mi problema radica en la segunda parte, en la funcion de "devuelvoDatos". Yo quiero hacer un reordeanmiento en base al promedio, quiero que se me ordene tanto el promedio como el nombre, asi me queda parejo. Alguno puede entender este problemita, porque ya estuve pensando bastante y no me funciona la cabeza. Tambien estaria bueno una explicacion si se puede, gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: y no esta copiando?